# Unable to render the correct result of ng-new app

Tags: angular, npm

I am unable to obtain the angular app after running 'ng new my-app' command.

These are the following outputs I get after running the command -

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UaTQe.png) Running 'ng new-mean' app

[image]

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/17USt.png) After selecting VS Code and clicking on OK -

I get following page  'ng' -

[image]

However, I fail to obtain the entire angular app with app.component.ts/.spec/.css/.html

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try putting your app name between double quotes since it has a dash in the name :

ng n “app-name”

Comment: Hi yoan, thanks for the suggestion. However, doing this did not make any difference.

Comment: I see your terminal is in powershell, can you try running the same command in normal cmd instead